# How to access content in another database from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, multiple-databases

I have two databases, one that is for my web-app and the other is for my android app. I wish to occasionally allow the Android app to query and insert into the table in the database for the web-app, but do not know how to do so.

Is it simply an SQL query but with the specifying parameter for which database it is ie.

select * from webAppsDB.WebAppTable...?

How is this managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `USE` statement first, like

```
 USE webAppsDB;

 SELECT * FROM WebAppTable
```

Comment: I was experimenting and tried using "SELECT * FROM databaseName.databaseTable", and it worked. Is this more or less secure than what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Eatlon: I though initially that you have problem with the `SELECT` with database name included as you have shown in your OP. Hence I show you the alternative. Now, as far as security is concern, the only thing that I could think is, is that your version means that those databases should be in one location & one server but mine could be put in different locations. So, which means with 1 location if security is broken then all other databases would be expose.